# How to pattern match the parent trait (or class, or object) of case classes?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, abstract-syntax-tree, case-class

I am trying to match all binary operators in a single `case` clause, but the following code gives the error:

```
object BinOp is not a case class, nor does it have a valid unapply/unapplySeq member
Note: def unapply(a: AST.this.Expr, b: AST.this.Expr): Option[(AST.this.Expr, AST.this.Expr)] exists in object BinOp, but it cannot be used as an extractor as it has more than one (non-implicit) parameter.
```

Core code to traverse the tree:

```
tree match {
    case ... other ... cases
    case BinOp(a, b) => traverse(a), traverse(b)
}
```

The AST classes are as follows:

```
sealed trait Expr

case class Num(value: java.lang.Number) extends Expr

sealed trait BinOp extends Expr {
  val a, b: Expr
}

object BinOp {
  def unapply(a: Expr, b: Expr): Option[(Expr, Expr)] = Some(a, b)
}

case class Add(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends BinOp

case class Sub(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends BinOp

case class Mul(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends BinOp

case class Div(a: Expr, b: Expr) extends BinOp
```

The code segments are hugely simplified for illustration purposes.

Comment: I am actually looking for a generic solution to traverse any Node that contains another; smells like Applicative/Functor or some other esoteric Haskell concepts. Any "traversable" node would be matched, e.g.

Comment: viyps, it'd be better if you added that comment as an edit to your question

Comment: Could you also provide a little more context about how you're going to be traversing over these Nodes? Do you just want to make them Iterable or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a misconception about how extractor objects work. You can think of `unapply` as the dual of `apply`, although it isn't always so.

Suppose instead of having `Add` as a case class with the `apply` method already made for you, you made it an ordinary class and put the `apply` method in a companion object:

```
object Add {
  def apply(a: Expr, b: Expr): Add = ???
}
```

The `unapply` method is just that, but with the input and output types switched (and inside an `Option`).

```
//Could also be a Some[(Expr,Expr)], as far as I can tell
def unapply(add: Add): Option[(Expr, Expr)] = (add.a, add.b)
```

Since the output of the `apply` method is just one value, the input of your `unapply` method is a single value, and since the `apply` method has multiple inputs, the `unapply` method has multiple outputs, or pretends to do so by using a tuple. There's a little more to it, but [this page](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html) from the documentation will be in more in depth than I.

**Edit**: @jwvh has pointed out that you don't need to return an `Option` from an `unapply` method - it can be any type with the methods `isEmpty` and `get`.

---

Since you also mentioned that you want to abstract over any sort of node that contains other nodes, I'd like to point out that if you're going to use pattern matching, you'll still have to make your own `unapply` method for each sort of node (or make it a case class).

Comment: Thanks, very clear now! I ended up making Expr an extension of Iterable, so each type of Node (like BinOp) can provide how it is traversed.

Comment: Just a point of interest: the `unapply()` return type must have the `isEmpty` method, to indicate that the match failed/succeeded, and the `get` method, to access the matched value. `Option` provides both so that's often convenient. Otherwise `unapply()` is free to return anything. It need not be a reflection of the `apply()` factory method (but it usually is).

Comment: @jwvh Thanks for the info, I always assumed it had to be an Option or Some.

Answer (score 5):

The error message seems informative

```
def unapply(a: AST.this.Expr, b: AST.this.Expr): Option[(AST.this.Expr, AST.this.Expr)] 
exists in object BinOp, but it cannot be used 
as an extractor as it has more than one (non-implicit) parameter.
```

so `unapply` method should be defined with single parameter, say something like so

```
object BinOp {
  def unapply(binOp: BinOp): Option[(Expr, Expr)] = Some(binOp.a, binOp.b)
}
```